# Print class type without module prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a bunch of class types (derived from `type`). When I print them, I get stuff like:

```
...
<class 'Default.new_templates.NewSnippetCommand'>
<class 'Default.new_templates.NewSyntaxCommand'>
<class 'Default.pane.ClosePaneCommand'>
<class 'Default.pane.FocusNeighboringGroup'>
<class 'Default.pane.MoveToNeighboringGroup'>
<class 'Default.pane.NewPaneCommand'>
<class 'Default.pane.SetMaxColumns'>
...
```

I would like to print:

```
...
NewSnippetCommand
NewSyntaxCommand
ClosePaneCommand
FocusNeighboringGroup
MoveToNeighboringGroup
NewPaneCommand
SetMaxColumns
...
```

How can I get to the class name part and leave out the module part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`__name__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__):

```
>>> type(OrderedDict())
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
>>> type(OrderedDict()).__name__
'OrderedDict'
```

Comment: Note that you're on IPython, which has different default display behavior from ordinary Python `print` or the ordinary interactive mode.

Comment: ...and you just edited the input prompts to `>>>`, but the output behavior is still IPython behavior instead of ordinary interactive interpreter behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The name of a class is the `__name__` attribute:

```
print(whateverclass.__name__)
```